# How do you import runbook to azure resource group from the command line

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, command-line-interface, azure-pipelines

I have a DevOps pipeline for setting up various resources within a resource group in Azure.

As part of the pipeline I would like to import a runbook to the resource group, and set up a schedule for it to run within the portal (not set up a DevOps schedule).

The docs explain how to create a runbook from the azure cli:

```
az automation runbook create --automation-account-name "myAutomationAccount" --resource-group "rg" --name "myRunbook" --type "PowerShell" --location "East US 2"
```

but do not explain how import the runbook from a DevOps repo.

How do I import the runbook from a DevOps pipeline using the cli.

Also how can I create a schedule in the portal (using the cli within the DevOps pipeline) on which to run the runbook?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to do it using the following commands with the appropriate arguments passed through `--automation-account-name --name --resource-group --type Powershell --location` for the first call etc:

```
az automation runbook create

az automation runbook replace-content --content @./Repo_name/runbook_name.ps1

az automation runbook publish
```

Comment: This `az cli` worked for me from inside a PowerShell script: `az automation runbook replace-content --content "$starterPs1" --resource-group $rgName --automation-account-name $acctName --name $rnBkName` Note that I did *have* to put quotes around `"$starterPs1"`. The value of `$starterPs1` was an ASCII encoded string of the PowerShell source code for the Runbook.  Also, I could not figure out a way to get CRLF into the source code of that string so, the code in my runbook was all on a single line (delimited as needed with semicolons).

Answer (score 0):

I import runbooks regularly. But I go a little different way. In Azure DevOps, I call a webhook with parameters and then start a runbook that imports the runbooks from Azure DevOps.
In addition, I no longer use the PowerShell modules for the import but do everything via the API, which is much faster.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/runbook/create-or-update

First, I create the runbook as a draft, adding the content and publishing the runbook.

It can also be done the other way, directly from Azure DevOps, but Azure Automation is my main tool, so I did it there. Of course, there is still source control in Azure Automation, where you can also have the code imported automatically. But I can do everything the same way with the runbook, and I'm very flexible with the webhook!

Stefan

Comment: Thanks Stefan - I figured out how to do it from DevOps with the cli

Answer (score 0):

For creating the runbook, inserting the content, publishing the runbook, creating a scedule and connecting the runbook to a schedule, we have this Azure CLI code for powershell:

```
az automation runbook create

az automation runbook replace-content --content @./folder_name/runbook_name.ps1

az automation runbook publish

az automation schedule create 

Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook
```

But as some of us experienced, the content of runbook_name.ps1 is cut off, after the first **CRLF**.
Why do some of us have this issue and others not?

Apparently, when running in an Azure Devops Pipeline the difference is the agent. Some parts of my pipeline needs a `windows-latest` agent. But after switching this job (pool/vmImage) to a `ubuntu-latest` agent, the whole file was imported and not only the first line of code.

Furthermore, I prefer creating the runbook, schedule an job creation via Bicep and only uses the this code for the insertion of je content:

```
az automation runbook replace-content --content @./folder_name/runbook_name.ps1
```

This is the only part of the pipeline, which has to run in a **linux agent**.

The bicep code I use:

```
resource parent_resource 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts@2022-08-08' existing = {
  name: parentName
}

resource deployRunbook 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks@2022-08-08' = {
  name: runbookName
  parent: parent_resource
  location: location
  properties: {
    description: description
    runbookType: 'PowerShell7'
    publishContentLink: {
      //dummy url as I want to use a file from an artifact in the Azure Devops pipeline
      uri: 'https://google.com'
    }
  }
}

resource schedule 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/schedules@2022-08-08' = {
  name: scheduleName
  parent: parent_resource
  properties: {
    advancedSchedule: {
      weekDays: weekDays
    }
    description: description
    frequency: frequency
    interval: any(1)
    startTime: dateTimeAdd('${todayDate}T${startTime}', dateTimeToEpoch('${todayDate}T${startTime}') > nowTicks + offsetSeconds ? 'P0D' : 'P1D')
  }
}

resource jobschedule 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/jobSchedules@2022-08-08' = {
  //the name of a jobSchedule must be a guid!
  name: jobscheduleId
  parent: parent_resource
  properties: {
    runbook: {
      name: runbookName
    }
    schedule: {
      name: scheduleName
    }
  }
}
```